# SetInterval keeps setting when changing pages

Tags: javascript

So, I have a JavaScript issue that is probably as old as time, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a form that takes up the whole page and has next and back buttons so the user can travel back and forth through the questions. (**Single page app**, no full refresh. If there was this would be easy!)

One of the requirements is to have a timeout function. So after they are idle after a cretin amount of time it logs them out to protect their information. The issue is that my interval keeps adding a new one every time I flip back and forth new pages. Thus creating multiple timers and insanity.

My code kind of looks like this.

```
 var idle = 0;
 var idleIntervalTimer = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); //This is what keeps being called
 var counter = 0;
 var timeout = 30;
 var count = 20;
 var resetCount = 20;

document.onmousemove = function() {
  if(app.timer.get('available') === 'Yes'){ //I'm just using this to make sure that they have not already been logged out
       count = resetCount;
       idle = 0;
       app.warning.close();
    }
};

function timerIncrement() {
  if(app.timer.get('available') === 'Yes'){
     console.log(idle);
     idle = idle + 1;

     if (idle > 19 && count >= 0) { 
        count = count;
        app.warning.show({ //This is just a warning message that shows up at the top of the page counting down before the app closes.
           message: 'Logging out in <span class="warn">' + count + '</span> seconds.'
        });

      if(count != null || count >= 0){
          count=count-1;

         if (count === 0 && count != 'null'){
             resetTimer();
             app.workflow.resetWorkflow();
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }


function resetTimer(){
   count = resetCount;
   idle = 0;
   clearInterval(counter);
   clearInterval(idleIntervalTimer);
    app.warning.close();
}
```

I have tried a few different things. One being that I would set a blank variable at the top and use that blank variable to set the interval, but that didn't seem to work. I have also tried to detect if the interval was still active, but I don't really want to clear the interval, just not create another. Some help would be apprenticed very much!

Comment: Are these full page naviagations? If so, navigating the page should destroy all existing intervals (it should reset the javascript runtime completely). It looks like we're missing quite a bit of code for a diagnostic. For instance, I see you clearing an interval named `counter` but it's never created.

Comment: It's a single page app, so while the page 'changes' it's not really changing.

Comment: Where is this init code run? Can you define the interval higher up, so that it's not recreated every time?

Comment: @Teemu The conditions do pass. I can run through this fine on the first page many times before running into the set interval problem stated above when traveling through the pages.

Comment: @DylanWatt, I can't put that code any higher than it already is. I'm within backbone and it's a very complicated structure how the pages and controls are set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that code gets called on every page flip. Don't set the interval timer immediately. You should create a function that will first clear it and then set.

For example do this instead:

```
var idleIntervalTimer;

function initIdleIntervalTimer(){
 clearInterval(idleIntervalTimer);
 idleIntervalTimer = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
}

initIdleIntervalTimer();
```

Or try switching it the timer to the global scope, get rid of var idleIntervalTimer and do this:

```
clearInterval(window.idleIntervalTimer);
window.idleIntervalTimer = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000);
```

Comment: This solution is still creating a bazillion intervals.

Comment: Does each page run this code in it's own scope? If so, you will need code to clear the interval on the page that is leaving. Or make sure this code is global to the app.

Comment: It's a single page app. This is run every single time they change pages to grab  the right variables and things it needs from the database.

Comment: I know it is a SPA. I'm wondering if you are creating multiple instances of this code every time the page changes. Because this code destroys the original timer and then creates a new one. So as long as the app is just using this one instance of idleIntervalTimer, there is no way to create multiple intevals.

Comment: I do not believe I am creating multiple instances of the code. How it works, I click next it runs through this view setting everything up including this code in a afterRender function and then when you hit next it runs through the same view to create it again. I don't know why, but even having the clearInterval above setting it up is still creating multiple instances of it.

Comment: Ok, so you are creating new instances of this code. You should create a separate module or object for this and any time you need to call it, the module should be able to keep track of the timer.

Comment: try switching from var idleIntervalTimer to just window.idleIntervalTimer. that may be the simplest way to solve your issue right now without rewriting a lot of your code.

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way to handle this is to implement OnDestroy and override the following method:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    // stop auto refresh alerts on page exit.
    clearInterval(this.refreshInterval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ugly, but

```
 window.clearInterval(localStorage['idleInterval'])
 var idleIntervalTimer = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); //This is what keeps being called
 window.localStorage['idleInterval'] = idleIntervalTimer;
```

EDIT: If you dont want to clear, wrap the entire init in a flag, eg

```
if (!window._intervalInitOccured){
    window._intervalInitOccured = true;
    //continue init
```

Comment: I don't really want to clear the interval though, just not call it a million times. nd ugly is ok as long as it works! :)

Comment: Is there a reason why the mouse move won't work anymore? It's counting down, but I can't get the mouse move to reset it.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you are putting things on the window?

Comment: I'm putting it on the window because you need access to some type of higher scope that can remember state across "reload." I'd prefer something better than global, but you said that you don't have access to a higher scope in your app. Our options are then global (window), localStorage, or maybe cookies. localStorage and cookies will remember across real page loads, which means you wouldn't reinit when you actually want to. So window seems the "lowest" scope you can use for this. I don't know why the mousemove code broke, is it inside the init, and the init is running correct (console.log)?

Comment: I think the core of the issue is just that you have code here that's meant to be app level, but you're putting it in a controller that's for a view partial, which is why (i assume) it's re running. The good solution is to have code thats meant to control the app run in an app level controller. Anything else will be a little hacky (it's fine, we've all been there) and will involve stuff like putting flags on the global scope.

Comment: I have it right after were  I'm declaring the variables and this code. It was working fine before so I'm not sure why that is broken now. It seems to run through it, just not actually do anything on mouse move. It's actually in a view and not a controller :) and I can't run this app level because the variables I have set defined up above are not really that way. Each of those is garbing  a value from a users preference which is only accessible page level because we have scanning and payment stuff we want to give them more time with.